# Error executing aapt

Tags: android

I am getting the error when i try to build my app :

`Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/faizal/DEV/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt`

This started after i used the SDK Manager to delete the existing build-tools(19.0.3) and got the latest one(20). The location mentioned in the error(`...sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2`) did infact exist, but it was removed automatically by the SDK manager when i removed the old build-tools.

Now i just see a `20.0.0` folder in `sdk/build-tools`. If i use SDK Manager to download the `19.0.3` build tools again, it creates a `19.0.3` folder, not `android-4.4.2`.

What's going on? Why is ADT looking for a non existent folder? Where is it specified?

Comment: I randomly happens, in Eclipse. Simply go to the Errors tab and delete the error. Then run the project, and it will go. You might have to repeat the deletion a couple of times.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Ahh i will try it if i see it again. thanks. For now, another solution worked. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i resolved it :
Added this line to the project.properties file :

```
sdk.buildtools=20.0.0
```

Build works after this, even if i remove the line after a one time build.

It is probably because the workspace created using the old ADT was not properly migrated by the new ADT. I think so because this issue appeared only for the projects created with the old ADT.

Comment: I'm getting this problem in appcompat_v7, not in my project. Should I follow the same solution??

Comment: i am not sure. Maybe first try this in any project in the same workspace. If that does not work, try it in the appcompat_v7 project. Remember to remove the line after the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened after updating sdk tools. aapt and aidl files didn't exist in that folder, copied from other version folders.

Then deleted the errors (from "Problems" tab) and restarted eclipse.

Comment: If you are receiving this error, this is the solution. It literally cannot find the .aapt and aidl files. copy and paste from previous version folders. I also added the sdk.builtools=22.0.1 (a previous build number, any of your choice). With these steps I was finally able to get my projects working again. Thanks to the poster!

Comment: great answer, though I am not sure about the background...it works !